# CSS : Using same class within different media queries

Tags: css, media-queries

I have the following code :

```css
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .color {
    color: blue;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .color {
    color: red;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .color {
    color: green;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {

}
```

```html
<div class="color">Wow ji</div>
```

No matter what the screen size, `Wow ji` appears in green color only. What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: because what you are saying is at 767px or higher you want .color to be green you need to swap the order of your media queries around

Comment: *No matter what the screen size, `Wow ji` appears in green color only.* From the CSS you gave us this is not true. In resolutions below 768px it will probably not be green. Interesting that a question based such on an obviously problem is getting 3 upvotes so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

max-width is the maximum width at which these styles will be shown. A screen wider than the specified number will not use the styles associated with that rule. Similarly, min-width is the minimum width at which these styles will be shown. A screen narrower than the specified number will not use the styles associated with that rule. I have changed your code with `max-width` now its working fine all media queries , just resize the browser

```css
 @media ( min-width : 1200px) {
  .color{
    color: blue;
  }
}

@media ( max-width : 992px) {
  .color{
    color: red;
  }
}

@media(max-width:768px){
  .color{
    color: green;
  }
}

@media(max-width:767px) {
  .color{
    color: yellow;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="color">Wow ji</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

In CSS, it is the last corresponding style that is applied, so in your code, as long as the screen is at least 768px, it will appear green.

You need either to set a `max-width` in the first tests, or do them in the inverse order.

Answer (score 2):

Because what you are saying is at 768px or higher you want .color to be green you need to swap the order of your media queries around or use max-width

Comment: 768px or higher

Answer (score 1):

You have a bad syntax and usage, it's not even the same each time.
I would recommand doing like this :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) { // or whatever screen size
    .color {
        color: green;
    }
}
```

And you better add a `<meta>` `viewport` in your HTML to make your media queries working fine.
Some docs:
[MDN - media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)
[MDN - Using the viewport meta tag to control layout on mobile browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)